# Combo Box indexes handling

Tags: c#, combobox

Im developing c # application and my level is beginner, So i want help from you guys. in windows form application i have a combobox named as Audiocombobox and its indexes are 0--> MPEG Layer 1 and 1--> MPEG Layer 2 respectively . I have another combobox named as MPEGAudioBitrate. i want to restrict user that if user select MPEG Layer 1 from Audiocombobox different options dispalyed in  MPEGAudioBitrate and if user select  MPEG Layer 2 from Audiocombobox different options showed in  MPEGAudioBitrate , please help

Comment: handle `SelectedIndexChanged` event in `Audiocombobox` and write code there

Comment: Thanks for your comment

i make changes in my code as if user select MPEG Layer 1 then it display label and combobox for MPEG Layer 1 options and disable MPEG layer 2 Label and combobox and if   MPEG Layer 2 then it display label and combobox for MPEG Layer 2 options and disable MPEG layer 1 Label and combobox. it works for me but i want to write selected index whether from MPEG Layer 1 or 2 in a file if user select MPEGAudioBitrate of Layer 1 it write index it works but it also write index 0 for Layer 2 need your help to write in a file only once

Comment: if this help then accept my answer bellow. MERCI ;)

Comment: Proper UI design demands that you set the Enabled property to *false* if you don't want the user to select anything from a combobox.  So it is completely obvious that using the control is not useful.  Setting its Visible property to *false* is okayish too but tends to be disorienting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Handle `SelectedIndexChanged` event and write following code:

```
private void Audiocombobox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Audiocombobox.SelectedIndex == 0)
    {
        MPEGAudioBitrate.Items.Clear();
        //Add MPEGAudioBitrate items for MPEG Layer 1
    }
    else if (Audiocombobox.SelectedIndex == 1)
    {
        MPEGAudioBitrate.Items.Clear();
        //Add MPEGAudioBitrate items for MPEG Layer 2
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment i make changes in my code as if user select MPEG Layer 1 then it display label and combobox for MPEG Layer 1 options and disable MPEG layer 2 Label and combobox and if MPEG Layer 2 then it display label and combobox for MPEG Layer 2 options and disable MPEG layer 1 Label and combobox. it works for me but i want to write selected index whether from MPEG Layer 1 or 2 in a file if user select MPEGAudioBitrate of Layer 1 it write index it works but it also write index 0 for Layer 2 need your help to write in a file only once